# Oracle Apex 5.1 dynamic datepicker minDate moves calendar icon

Tags: jquery, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have two datepickers and am using a js DA to set the minDate of the end date to the value of the start date:

[image: start and end date datepickers]

[image: DA JS content]

However once this DA runs the calendar icon on the second dp moves to the left of the date field:

[image: datepickers after JS has executed]

Can someone please explain what's going on here and give me some guidance on how to prevent this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: Just tried to reproduce your error and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the cause and solution are explained by Maxime Tremblay here:
https://max-tremblay.blogspot.com/2018/03/datepicker-customization.html

Basically, changing the option is redrawing the item without taking into account some APEX specific customizations in the markup.

You can chain on to your existing line of code to fix it:

```
end.datepicker('option', minDate, dt)
  .next('button')
  .addClass('a-Button a-Button--calendar');
```

Comment: Thank you, Dan, that's sorted it.

Comment: That's awesome! :)